# JTable without horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

How to create a JTable without vertical and horizontal lines in it...

Answer (score 11):

Try playing around with `setShowGrid()`, `setShowVerticalLines()` and `setShowHorizontalLines()`

**[setShowVerticalLines()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowVerticalLines(boolean))**

> Sets whether the table draws vertical
>   lines between cells. If
>   showVerticalLines is true it does; if
>   it is false it doesn't.

**Examples:**

```
table.setShowGrid(false);
table.setShowVerticalLines(false);

table.setShowGrid(false);
table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jTable4.setShowHorizontalLines(true); // only HorizontalLines
  jTable4.setShowVerticalLines(true); //  only VerticalLines
  jTable4.setShowGrid(true);          // show Horizontal and Vertical
  jTable4.setGridColor(Color.yellow); // change line color
```

use this code :)